# SQL - Inline select statements - issue when @retailer_id = null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query, which works perfectly when I supply the retailer_id parameter with a value.

```
SELECT      reda.RetailerId,
                (   SELECT      SUM(reda.Purchases)
                    FROM        RetailerDaily                   reda
                    WHERE       (reda.RetailerId                = @retailer_id
                    OR          @retailer_id                    IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 >= @date_from
                    OR          @date_from                      IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 <= @date_to
                    OR          @date_to                        IS NULL)
                    GROUP BY    reda.RetailerId)                                    AS Purchases,

                (   SELECT      SUM(reda.PurchaseTotal)
                    FROM        RetailerDaily                   reda
                    WHERE       (reda.RetailerId                = @retailer_id
                    OR          @retailer_id                    IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 >= @date_from
                    OR          @date_from                      IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 <= @date_to
                    OR          @date_to                        IS NULL)
                    GROUP BY    reda.RetailerId)                                    AS PaymentsTotal,

                (   SELECT      SUM(reda.Refunds)
                    FROM        RetailerDaily                   reda
                    WHERE       (reda.RetailerId                = @retailer_id
                    OR          @retailer_id                    IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 >= @date_from
                    OR          @date_from                      IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 <= @date_to
                    OR          @date_to                        IS NULL)
                    GROUP BY    reda.RetailerId)                                    AS Refunds,

                (   SELECT      SUM(reda.RefundTotal)
                    FROM        RetailerDaily                   reda
                    WHERE       (reda.RetailerId                = @retailer_id
                    OR          @retailer_id                    IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 >= @date_from
                    OR          @date_from                      IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 <= @date_to
                    OR          @date_to                        IS NULL)
                    GROUP BY    reda.RetailerId)                                    AS RefundsTotal,

                (   SELECT      SUM(reda.OffersOptedInto)
                    FROM        RetailerDaily                   reda
                    WHERE       (reda.RetailerId                = @retailer_id
                    OR          @retailer_id                    IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 >= @date_from
                    OR          @date_from                      IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 <= @date_to
                    OR          @date_to                        IS NULL)
                    GROUP BY    reda.RetailerId)                                    AS OffersOptedInto,

                (   SELECT      SUM(reda.RedeemedOffers)
                    FROM        RetailerDaily                   reda
                    WHERE       (reda.RetailerId                = @retailer_id
                    OR          @retailer_id                    IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 >= @date_from
                    OR          @date_from                      IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 <= @date_to
                    OR          @date_to                        IS NULL)
                    GROUP BY    reda.RetailerId)                                    AS RedeemedOffers,

                (   SELECT      SUM(reda.RedeemedOfferTotal)
                    FROM        RetailerDaily                   reda
                    WHERE       (reda.RetailerId                = @retailer_id
                    OR          @retailer_id                    IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 >= @date_from
                    OR          @date_from                      IS NULL)
                    AND         (reda.DateStart                 <= @date_to
                    OR          @date_to                        IS NULL)
                    GROUP BY    reda.RetailerId)                                    AS RedeemedOfferTotal

    FROM        RetailerDaily                                                       reda

    WHERE       (reda.RetailerId                                                    = @retailer_id
    OR          @retailer_id                                                        IS NULL)
    AND         (reda.DateStart                                                     >= @date_from
    OR          @date_from                                                          IS NULL)
    AND         (reda.DateStart                                                     <= @date_to
    OR          @date_to                                                            IS NULL)

    GROUP BY    reda.RetailerId
```

However, when I pass in retailer_id as null I receive the following error message

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Can anybody shed some light onto how to resolve this issue as I can't seem to work it out.

Thanks in advance

Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented before, this is expected behavior. You are using subqueries as expressions, and they are only allowed to return a single value. If you pass in NULL, they will produce multiple values.

Why on Earth are you even using so many subqueries? Your query could be simplified as follows:

```
SELECT      RetailerId,
            SUM(Purchases) AS Purchases,
            SUM(PurchaseTotal) AS PaymentsTotal,
            SUM(Refunds) AS Refunds,
            SUM(RefundTotal) AS RefundsTotal,
            SUM(OffersOptedInto) AS OffersOptedInto,
            SUM(RedeemedOffers) AS RedeemedOffers,
            SUM(RedeemedOfferTotal) AS RedeemedOfferTotal

    FROM        RetailerDaily

    WHERE       (RetailerId = @retailer_id
    OR          @retailer_id IS NULL)
    AND         (DateStart >= @date_from
    OR          @date_from IS NULL)
    AND         (DateStart <= @date_to
    OR          @date_to IS NULL)

    GROUP BY    RetailerId
```

Comment: Cheers dude, I kind of had this previously but didn't notice the little differences first time round, many thanks for the help its much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you are using `GROUP BY    reda.RetailerId` if there are multiple RetailerId's it will return multiple records, so remove group by clause.

Comment: I removed the group by clause's from the in-line select statements, however now every record returned displays the same values just with a unique RetailerId

Comment: that will happen, you are passing the variable as null so how will be the result different? it will show the total sum.

Comment: It is obvious the OP does not want the total sums, but the sums for each retailer. Therefore, while removing the GROUP BY clauses will make the error go away, it will also make the results useless.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I am having, not sure what direction to go down as I think I need to re-structure the whole query